# python plot bar range with months avarage does not fit

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have created this simple dataframe. This dataframe is the result of a monthly resample (with sum).

here the example

```
dates;rev
2018-01-31;-2
2018-02-28;-5
2018-03-31;-7
2018-04-30;-8
2018-05-31;-9
2018-06-30;-2
2018-07-31;1
2018-08-31;2
2018-09-30;3
2018-10-31;4
2018-11-30;4
2018-12-31;5
```

When I try to plot it as follows:

```
axs.bar(dR.index.values, dR.iloc[:],color='purple')
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter(r'\textbf{%B}')) 
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

I get a result that is not what I expect:

[image]

The bar are not width enough to cove all months. They are a simple vertical line. In addition only some months appear as ticket.

It seems that all is due to the fact the data are not properly categorized.

Sorry, but I do not have a clue on this. I have tried to figure out a solution  by searching on The internet but nothing comes out.

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

it is a simple solution, you have to use axs.xaxis_date(): try this:

```
axs.bar(dR.index.values, dR.iloc[:],color='purple', width=10)
axs.xaxis_date()
```

Just to you to know and check I've done this code bellow to plot the data you gave and got a nice result:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[{"dates":'2018-01-31',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-02-28',"rev":-5},
{"dates":'2018-03-31',"rev":-7},
{"dates":'2018-04-30',"rev":-8},
{"dates":'2018-05-31',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-06-30',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-07-31',"rev":1},
{"dates":'2018-08-31',"rev":2},
{"dates":'2018-09-30',"rev":3},
{"dates":'2018-10-31',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-11-30',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-12-31',"rev":5}]

df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df["dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df.dates)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.bar(df.dates, df.rev,color='purple', width=10)
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks. It's wonderful. Now I have a problem with this example related to the format of my data which does not allowed me to get the same result. Could I ask\report the problem here? Is it better to open another treat?

Comment: Since it is an unrelated issue I think it is better to open a new treat